# When the linux kernel reports time as spent servicing "soft interrupts", precisely what does it mean?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have top showing high activity in the %si column for several cpus. Sar reports something similar.

Q1) What are the possibilities for what might be executing in the kernel? It appears that "softirqs" themselves are more or less outdated, and generally function as a mechanism to implement other interfaces, including tasklets, rculists, and I'm not sure what else. I'd like to get a comprehensive list.

Q2) How can I get more precise information on what's actually running as "soft interrupts" on my test system?

As it happens, I have strong suspicions that a particular device driver is involved, since the hard interrupt % is also high, and only on whatever cpu that's presently handling this particular device's interrupt :-) But I haven't so far found anything in the driver source code that looks to me as if it could result in softirq activity. I'm probably missing the obvious, so I'm asking for help ;-)

My kernel is rather outdated - 2.6.32 based (RHEL 6.1, I believe) but I doubt that matters too much for questions this general.

Comment: I-am-not-a-kernel-hacker, but I always think about the book "Linux Kernel Development" by Robert Love when people talk about the linux kernel. If you actually want to understand what they do and how they work you should spend some time reading that. I haven't, hence I cannot give a complete answer. Loosely though, interrupt handlers are often split into top (immediate) and bottom (deferred) halves. softirqs are an implementation of bottom halves with tight locking, while tasklets are a type of softirq that are easier to use and therefore used almost everywhere in 2.6.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, timer functions and NAPI callbacks (in network drivers) are also executed in softirq context.

Comment: Robert Love's book is something close to a bible for anyone new to working on the linux kernel. Unfortunately though it doesn't go into enough depth on this - just enough for me to know there might be dragons lurking.

Comment: @caf - `perf top` rocks. Thanks for that suggestion. It hasn't solved this problem, but it's given me lots of insight into what the problem driver is smoking ;-)